# No inserta campo tipo Date en mi BD

Tags: php, html, html5, phpexcel

Realizo un modulo de importación masiva de un archivo de excel.csv pero en mi campo de fecha (DATE) no inserta correctamente los datos, solo inserta 0000-00-00, los demás campos en la importación lo hace sin problema solo es en el campo fecha.

Este es un ejemplo de una linea del archivo de excel.csv

```
 7;01/12/2017;15:02:00;;;
 10;26/11/2017;22:37:00;;;
```

Gracias / Saludos

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {//nos permite recepcionar una variable que si exista y que no sea null
    require_once("conexion_excel.php");
    require_once("functions.php");

    $archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
    $archivo_copiado= $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $archivo_guardado = "copia_".$archivo;

    //echo $archivo."esta en la ruta temporal: " .$archivo_copiado;

    if (copy($archivo_copiado ,$archivo_guardado )) {
        //echo "se copeo correctamente el archivo temporal a nuestra carpeta de trabajo <br/>";
    }else{
        //echo "hubo un error <br/>";
    }

    if (file_exists($archivo_guardado)) {

         $fp = fopen($archivo_guardado,"r");//abrir un archivo
         $rows = 0;
         while ($datos = fgetcsv($fp , 1000 , ";")) {
                $rows ++;
               // echo $datos[0] ." ".$datos[1] ." ".$datos[2]." ".$datos[3] ."<br/>";
            if ($rows > 1) {
                $resultado = insertar_datos($datos[0],$datos[1],$datos[2]);
            if($resultado){
                //echo "se inserto los datos correctamente<br/>";
            }else{
                //echo "no se inserto <br/>";
            }
            }
         }



    }else{
        echo "No existe el archivo copiado <br/>";
    }

}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### El problema

El formato para guardar fechas en la base de datos es `YYYY-MM-DD`, por lo tanto, si tu dato viene dado así: `01/12/2017` no es válido para ser insertado en la base de datos.

### La solución

Habría que hacer que tu dato sea apto para ser insertado, y que además sea correcto.

Lo puedes hacer mediante el método [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) de la clase `DateTime` de PHP del siguiente modo:

```
$csvFecha=$datos[1]; //Columna donde está el dato

/*
  *Esta llamada creará un objeto fecha 
  *formateado así por ejemplo: 2017-12-01
*/

$sqlFecha=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $csvFecha)->format('Y-m-d');
$resultado = insertar_datos($datos[0],$sqlFecha,$datos[2]);
```

**NOTA:** Dado que veo otra columna con una hora, ten en cuenta que, si se trata del mismo dato, podrías guardar en una sola columna del tipo `DATETIME`, tanto la fecha como lo hora, precisamente por eso se llaman `DATETIME`, porque sirven para guardar la fecha y el tiempo.

Espero te sirva.